# Need to merge information from four files together

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, merge

I have a 2 big files, both include segments of information I want, I have extracted the information into output files and now I have 4 files which hold the information I need.

What I want to do is merge the information from the four files into 1 file, in a neat format as long as it is a line by line format including 4 columns and separated by commas, and I want to be able to put something at the top of the file when it opens as to let the user know what information is in the columns.  Is this possible in python>?

Here is the info I want to merge:

```
'/usr/share/doc/HTML/es/kioslave/index.docbook' 

Redhat 7.3' 

Linux' 

D84270022E57F1850C8464FA432ADFF99588157B'
```

every line is 1 line from the files I have, they go for many lines so I cannot post the whole thing, but that is an example of the info.

Comment: It might be helpful for us to see an example that we could troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function is used to combine multiple sources into a single tuple.

```
for row in zip(file1, file2, file3, file4):
    # output the 4 column values in row
```

Comment: this worked perfect but is there a way I may get rid of the '/n' in between them

Comment: and how would I make the output format row by row instead of all mashed together

Comment: @BrayanHernandez, the easiest way is to call `.strip()` on each string before you output it. Then add a `\n` to the end of a row.

Comment: fhand.write(line.strip() + pathNames.readline().strip() + os.readline().strip() + product.readline().strip() + '/n')  <-- like that?

Comment: thank you :) I got it going...was using /n instead of \n ><                             One more thing I have a question on, is how to add a header to the top of the output file by adding to my code.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible--look at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module, which is most likely what you need. It's easy to use.

You'll be creating a comma separated value file (.csv) where the first row will be headers indicating the contents of each row, i.e.

```
path,distro,os,serial
'/usr/share/doc/HTML/es/kioslave/index.docbook' ,'Redhat 7.3', 'Linux', D84270022E57F1850C8464FA432ADFF99588157B'
```

Comment: cvs module? I am still fairly new at this and have not much experience.

Comment: edited the post to add a little info--just read through the documentation I linked. This is one of the very first real-world uses I put python to, so I'm confident you'll be able to work it out from there.